# Tracking Down Missing RDEPENDS Items

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded

Is there a general process for tracking down missing RDEPENDS items that are listed in bitbake errors like this:

```
ERROR: program-3.2.166.0-r2 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /usr/bin/program contained in package program requires libz.so.1(ZLIB_1.2.3.4), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_program? [file-rdeps]
```

Simply adding the undecorated item (libz in this case) to RDEPENDS works sometimes, but not always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `oe-pkgdata-util find-path '*libz.so*'` to find the actual package providing the missing library which you can then add to `RDEPENDS`.